# Error that I couldn't solve

Tags: android-manifest

Error that I couldn't solve regarding android manifest:

> `AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>".`

Can somebody write me the 'correct' version of it? Thanks.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket">
    <permission android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"/>
    <permission android:description="@string/permdesc_install_shortcut" android:label="@string/permlab_install_shortcut" android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
    <permission android:description="@string/permdesc_uninstall_shortcut" android:label="@string/permlab_uninstall_shortcut" android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>
    <permission android:description="@string/permdesc_read_settings" android:label="@string/permlab_read_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.READ_SETTINGS" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission android:description="@string/permdesc_write_settings" android:label="@string/permlab_write_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS" android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <permission android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ADVANCED_WIDGET_API"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home" android:label="@string/application_name" android:largeHeap="@bool/config_largeHeap" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.LauncherApplication" android:process="android.process.acore">
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home" android:label="@string/application_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.LauncherFacade" android:theme="@style/Theme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.Launcher" android:stateNotNeeded="true" android:taskAffinity="com.lenovo.launcher_1" android:theme="@style/Theme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:enabled="false" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.FakeHome" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home" android:label="@string/toggle_weight_watcher" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.ToggleWeightWatcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/menu_desktop_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.SeniorSettings">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.action.DESKTOP_SETTING"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_about_us" android:label="@string/about_lenovo_desktop_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.AboutLenovoDesktop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/customapp_title" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.CustomApppSettingsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/customapp_title" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.CustomApppSettingsNewActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/gesture_settings_title" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.GestureSettings" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/menu_sense_settings" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.ProfileSettings">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/lbk"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home" android:label="@string/debug_memory_activity" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.MemoryDumpActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.downloadinfo.provider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.networksdk.download.DownloadContentProvider"/>
        <service android:enabled="@bool/debug_memory_enabled" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.MemoryTracker"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.PreloadReceiver" android:permission="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.PRELOAD_WORKSPACE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.InstallShortcutReceiver" android:permission="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.UninstallShortcutReceiver" android:permission="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher3.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
                <action android:name="com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.UserInitializeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_INITIALIZE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.PackageChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:authorities="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.settings" android:exported="true" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.LauncherProvider" android:readPermission="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.READ_SETTINGS" android:writePermission="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.disable_beam_default" android:value="true"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.VersionUpdateActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.Dialog.Alert">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.BackupAndRestoreCloudReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="10000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED"/>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.Intent.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_DELETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.BackupAndRestoreService"/>
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/allapp_icon" android:label="@string/all_app" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.customizer.AllAppShortCut" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.ThemeActivity" android:process=":Theme" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.Holo.Light.ThemeCenter.Custom.Default">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.THEME_SETTING_MARKET"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.ThemeDetailActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.ThemeActivity" android:process=":Theme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.THEME_DETAIL_MARKET"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.WallpaperActivity" android:process=":Theme" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.Holo.Light.ThemeCenter.Custom.Default">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.WALLPAPER_SETTING_MARKET"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.NetWallpaperClassificationActivity" android:process=":Theme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.NET_WALLPAPER_CLASSIFICATION_MARKET"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.PreviewActivity" android:process=":Theme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.WALLPAPER_PREVIEW_MARKET"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.CropActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.PreviewActivity" android:process=":Theme"/>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.DownloadCompleteReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="launcher.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.LoaderCursor"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.themezipmarket.downloads" android:exported="true" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:multiprocess="true" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.downloads.DownloadProvider"/>
        <service android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.downloads.DownloadService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.backup.ProfileReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.action.ACTION_BACKUP_FILE"/>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.action.ACTION_HAVE_FILE"/>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.action.ACTION_RESTORE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:configChanges="locale|fontScale|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/menu_desktop_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings2.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcherhdmarket.action.DESKTOP_SETTING2"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.floatview.recent.RecentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="dialog.recentdialog"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.crop.CropActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.lenovo.launcher.theme.PreviewActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.SearchActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.FindListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/ThemeTranslucentForSearch"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.GotoFindWallpaper" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.DeviceDefaultLight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.GotoFindWallpaper"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/preview" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.LockscreenPreviewActivity" android:theme="@style/ThemeTranslucentForLockscreenPreview">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.SearchWallpaperPreviewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.lenovo.weather.service.AlarmTaskService"/>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.lenovo.weather.service.AutoLocationService"/>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.baidu.location.f"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lenovo.umeng.fb.ConversationActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.settings.UmengConversationActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lenovo.umeng.fb.ContactActivity"/>
        <meta-data android:name="UMENG_APPKEY" android:value="53c4c95556240bd163025690"/>
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/weather_preview" android:label="@string/widget_name_4x2" android:name="com.lenovo.laweather.activity.WeatherWidgetDefaultProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.LENOVOWIDGETS"/>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.LENOVO_WEATHER_WIDGETS"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.childrenmode.ChildrenModeGuide" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.CHILDREN_MODE_GUIDE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.search2.SearchDetailDialog" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.SearchDetail">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="dialog.searchdetaildialog"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.childrenmode.ChildrenModeSetting" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.action.CHILDREN_MODE_SETTING"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.umeng.update.net.DownloadingService" android:process=":DownloadingService"/>
        <activity android:name="com.umeng.update.UpdateDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|mcc|mnc|orientation|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Lockscreen.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/lockscreen_settings" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.SettingsActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.DeviceDefaultLight" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.LockscreenService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.LockscreenService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:label="@string/lockpassword_choose_your_pattern_header" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.lockpattern.ChooseLockPatternActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.DeviceDefaultLight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/lockpassword_confirm_your_pattern_header" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.lockpattern.ConfirmLockPatternActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.LeLauncher.DeviceDefaultLight">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.lockscreen.LockscreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/lock" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.onekeylock.OneKeyLockActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:description="@string/app_name" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.lenovo.launcher.onekeylock.AdminReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/lock_screen"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="lenovo_app_suskey" android:value="GooglePlay"/>
    </application>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You should really revise your app's requirements. Too many permission requests will discourage most users from installing it

Comment: Is that really a **minimal** example that exhibits the problem?  If not, then read [MCVE](/help/mcve) and trim it down to just the bit that causes the error.  That will save people's time, including your own.

Comment: Making the title more specific will help you get a better answer